# Convert 1d array to a 2d "row" array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change in javascript a **1d array to a 2d "row" array**:

var row1D = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
must be changed to:

var row2D = [["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]];
How do i solve this?

(The examples that I have change it to a 2d "column" array:
var column2D = [["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["D"], ["E"]])

```
var column2D = [];
  for (var i = row1D.length; i--;) {
    column2D[i] = [row1D[i]];
  }
```

Comment: Your array 2D kinda seems to be the same flat 1D but just inside a *second* array. Is this example on purpose? If its on purpose then `row2D.push(row1D)` solves your problem. Otherwise you need a correct example.

Comment: you could simply do 2dArray.push(1DArray);

Comment: Thanks! 2dArray.push(1DArray) works also!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the array, not the items.

```
column2D = [row1D];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Covert 1d array to a 2d "row" array:**

Thanks! This is the solution for me!

```
var row1D = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var row2D = [];
  for (var i = row1D.length; i--;) {
    row2D = [row1D];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and wrap each element in array

```js
var row1D = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var row2D = row1D.map(x => [x]);

console.log(row2D);
```